# Job History Logs for spark jobs submitted on YARN

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I observe that YARN jobs history logs are created in `/user/history/done` (*.jhist files) for all the mapreduce jobs like hive, pig etc. But for spark jobs submitted in `yarn-cluster` mode, the logs are not being created.

I would like to see resource utilization by spark jobs. Is there any other place where I can find the resource utilization by spark jobs (CPU, Memory etc). Or is there any configuration to be set so that the job history logs are created just like other mapreduce jobs.